# How to record webcam video signal with video4linux2?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, webcam, video4linux

I need to record a video from my webcam with ffmpeg.

I tried with this command : `ffmpeg -re -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 video.avi`.

And I received that : `The v4l2 frame is 24384 bytes, but 153600 bytes are expected`.

When I try the same operation with avconv with this command : `avconv -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 video.avi`  I received the same error.

But I can receive the video from my webcam with this command: `gstreamer-properties`.

How to configure v4l2 to get signal video from my webcam ?

Comment: WHat is video size of your input video (webcam)? Try to use option -s and specify size of video, like -s 640x480.

Comment: I tried with many different sizes. I tried to reduce frames, to change size, to change codecs, to delimit record time...

Comment: But when I try with the size 160x120 the program go in an infinite loop and don't send me any error or warning.

Comment: Ok. Please, provide full ffmpeg output when you run command and output of command "v4l2-ctl --all"

Comment: Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
    Driver name   : uvcvideo
    Card type     : HD Webcam C525
    Bus info      : usb-0000:00:0b.0-1
    Driver version: 3.8.13
    Capabilities  : 0x84000001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height  : 160/120  Pixel Format  : 'YUYV'
    Field         : None
    Bytes per Line: 320
    Size Image    : 38400
    Colorspace    : SRGB
Crop Capability Video Capture:
    Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 160, Height 120
    Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 160, Height 120
    Pixel Aspect: 1/1

Comment: Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Capabilities     : timeperframe
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
    Read buffers     : 0
Priority: 2

I received that and my last command set size at 160x120.
If I set size at 320x240 all this size settings will change to 320x240.

Comment: Have you tried set pixel format of input?

Comment: I tried some like mp4, avi, wma or h264.

Comment: You are talking about media containers and codecs. I'm talking about pixel format like 444yuv, 420yuv etc. See full list of available pixel formats using command "ffmpeg -pix_fmts"

Comment: I will try with different pixel format.

Comment: ffmpeg change automatically pixel format to yuyv422 whatever I set in the command.

Comment: I see. Ok if you use 160x120 you have valid output or not? Also try to set framerate to lower values, like 5-10 fps.

Comment: I have nothing if I use 160x120. The program do nothing after opening /dev/video0.I tried with different frame rates.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea then.

Comment: Thanks anyway, if someone else have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from virtual box.
It recognize my webcam the first time during my test but after just as a USB device.
I set USB device to webcam and now I can stream or convert videos with ffmpeg.